# How to connect TLS 1.2 with Java 1.4?

Tags: java, tls1.2, java1.4

I need to connect with a URL but I can only connect with TLS 1.2 and the Java version available is Java 1.4. Is it possible, and if so, how to do it?

Comment: "The EOL transition period began Dec, 11 2006 and will complete October 30th, 2008, when J2SE 1.4.2 will have reached its End of Service Life (EOSL). "    So it's not just old, it was end-of-lifed _over 10 years ago_.

Comment: What have you tried so far to get it working? Is there any error message?